# Reference to class method

Tags: function, c++11, reference, arguments

I would like to pass to a function a reference to a class method.

For example:

```
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
  int f(const int& val) const
  {
    return val+2;
  }
};

int caller(const std::function<int(const int&)>& f)
{
  return f(1);
}

int main()
{
  caller([](const int& val){return val+2;}); // OK
  Foo foo;
  caller(foo.f); // WRONG
  return 0;
}
```

How can I fix the second call of caller() (NB: Foo:f() is not static)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, function `f` doesn't use any member of `Foo` so it can be declared `static`

```
    static int f(const int& val)
```

and passed as:

```
    caller(&Foo::f);
```

But suppose that `f` cannot be declared `static` and you want to pass "reference" to member function of particular object.

You can use lambda in that case:

```
    Foo foo;
    caller(
       [&foo](const int& val){
          return foo.f(val);
       }
    );
```

`foo` object is captured in square brackets (in this case by reference) so that you can call `f` member function on that particular object.

Although it is not part of your question, I should add that it is not really useful to pass `int` by const reference, as you will not gain any performance improvement that way. Actually, your code will run slower than if you pass `int` by value.

Comment: Yeah, I know that f can be declared static but this is only a mock example. Your second solution works but actually you are forwarding the call of f() using a lambda, you are not passing to caller() a reference to f().

Comment: First about references to functions:
They are called function pointers. If you have member (non-static) function pointer, you cannot call it without object. No way.

About const int& vs int performance:
const int& and int usually have the same size so you will not gain any performance benefit by passing int by const reference. Moreover, any access to int variable will require one dereferencing and that is your perfomance penalty from that approach.

Comment: for completeness, there's also the std::bind option: `caller(std::bind(&Foo::f, &foo, _1));`

Comment: I didn't want to mention bind as lambda is usually more optimal solution in C++11 and bind is not really useful in C++14, as Scott Meyers described. IMHO, one who is beginner in C++ shouldn't even learn bind, apart from reading existing code. http://www.qa-systems.com/academy/burying-bind-wed-011014.html